# Fetching JSON data from firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

After my last question lead to a dead end I am now trying to fetch data as a JSON from the realtime database (which is usually accomplished by just adding '.json' to the end of the data link)

but when I then try to serialize the data it doesn't create a JSON and says that .length cannot be read of undefined even though in the console the data is there.

this is what I get from fetch():

```
Output:  {-MHqJuAp0XT1Ko780Cdx: {…}, -MHqfacixCOJeI_JSr__: {…}}

index.js?4360:36 OutputLenght:  undefined

index.js?4360:47 {-MHqJuAp0XT1Ko780Cdx: {…}, -MHqfacixCOJeI_JSr__: {…}}

index.js?4360:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myJson.slice is not a function
    at _callee2$ (index.js?4360:51)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
```

this is my code:

```
async fetchData(){
          
          const user = (await firebase.auth().currentUser);
          const fblink = await firebase.database().ref("events/public").toString()+".json?auth=" + (await user.getIdTokenResult()).token;

          return await fetch(fblink)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then((out) => {
            
            console.log('Output: ', out);
            return(out);
          }).catch(err =>{ console.error(err); return null});
    },

    async fetchEvents({dispatch,commit},{perPage})
    {
      const myJson = await dispatch("fetchData");
      commit("SET_EVENTS", myJson);
      commit("SET_ROWS", myJson.length );

      const displayEvents = myJson.slice(0,perPage);
      commit("SET_DISPLAY_EVENTS",displayEvents);
      commit("SET_ROWS" , myJson.length);
    }
```

and this is the data in the database:

```
{
  "public" : {
    "-MHqJuAp0XT1Ko780Cdx" : {
      "date" : "2020-09-09",
      "id" : 14,
      "img" : "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/743104050744262797/748929414607405197/IMG_20200828_173755.jpg",
      "name" : "TEST",
      "shortDesc" : "herllo",
      "start" : "22:57:00"
    },
    "-MHqfacixCOJeI_JSr__" : {
      "date" : "2020-09-01",
      "id" : 1,
      "img" : "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/743104050744262797/748929414607405197/IMG_20200828_173755.jpg",
      "name" : "asda",
      "shortDesc" : "dasdasda",
      "start" : "22:58:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: its just the snippet from the database, the fblink is in fact correct

Comment: Well I would start with testing the result of `const myJson = await dispatch("fetchData");` since based on error is `undefined`

Comment: but thats the awkward part in the preceding line out(wich is the var i return does have a value)

Comment: What is the dispatch function?

Comment: its in the vuex store
also it apears that out is not a list / array since length is undefined

Comment: I see. I don't have any experience with vuex, and yes `out` is an object.